# how to change the replacement of word in the specific line using sed command?

Tags: text-processing, sed

I have to change a word in the 4th line so I used this command:

```
sed -i '4 s/previous_word/new_word/' filename
```

and it worked perfectly.
But if I save the line number in a variable and try the same command I get this error:

```
$ sed -i '${line_no} s/previous_word/new_word/' filename
 error
 sed: -e expression #1, char 5: expected newer version of sed
```

How can I do this correctly?

Comment: Your error message looks weird for the syntax you use. Why should `sed` expect a newer version of itself there, I wonder?

Comment: Oh... I get it - actually that's the `v` command on a GNU `sed`. Weird that you managed to get all properly lexed grammar as far in as `prev`...

Answer (score 7):

Use double quotes instead of single quotes.

```
sed -i "${line_no}..."
```

See [Stack Overflow:Difference between single and double quotes in bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6697753/difference-between-single-and-double-quotes-in-bash)

Comment: better yet: `sed -i "${line_no}"'s/previous_word/new_word/' filename` - this avoids problems that might be caused by shell expansion of the rest of the instruction line